# Creating PowerShell module via .NET class library

Tags: .net, powershell, frameworks

I am building a PowerShell module in .NET.  I've read somewhere that PowerShell 3.0 targets .NET Framework 4.0 and so my class library project must also be targeting the same version.  My problem is I have existing projects that are targeting .NET Framework 4.5 and referencing them in my powershell module class library project using .NET 4.0 does not work, it does not see those project references unless they are the same version.  Is there a way around this or is PowerShell going to target .NET 4.5 soon?  Changing the .NET Framework version of my existing projects is not an option for me right now.  Any suggestions?

Comment: You does not have to target to `.NET Framework 4.0` to make module for PowerShell 3.0.

Comment: Also .NET 4.5/4.6 are "drop-in" replacements for 4.0. They are supposed to be compatible w 4.0 (unless you use new features in 4.5/4.6). So if your projects are based on 4.5  and they aren't working under under PS 3.0, it might be they are using 4.5 specific features. Or you could always move to PS4.0 or PS5.0. I'm guessing it's unlikely MS will go back to PS3.0 and update it for 4.5. BTW, if you want help with a particular error you are seeing, please post relevant code and error messages.